# Why can I not access a nodejs app on an AWS EC2 Instance?

Tags: express, iis, amazon-ec2, url-rewrite-module, windows-server-2019

I am currently trying to deploy a node js app on an AWS EC2 Windows Server 2019 instance. I am done with cloning my git repo and starting up my application and can access it within my EC2 instance.

To make my node application accessible I used the Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager and added the app under Default Web Site. I added the URL Rewrite module and added an inbound rule like so:

[image]

I can access the EC2 instance via its "Public DNS (IPv4)", which shows the default IIS Template: http://ec2-13-58-250-47.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com

But as soon as I add something to the path such as "/app", ":3000/app" or "/app:3000" I received "500" or "404" errors. What would be the correct path to access my app?

Other things I tried:

*Security Groups*

I googled a bit and most threads suggest checking the security group for the EC2 instance, which is what I have done. Here is a screenshot of my current security group:

[image: Security Group]

*Port*

My .env file does not contain a PORT, which is why I expect the app to use the hard-coded port 3000. To make sure i printed the port via `listener.address().port` and it uses 3000.

The app.js file looks like this:

```
const express = require("express")
const path = require("path")
const router = require("./router/auth.routes")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser")
const passport = require("passport")
const winston = require('./config/winston')
const { initialiseAuthentication } = require("./auth")
const { connectToDatabase } = require("./database/connection")
require("dotenv").config()

/**
 * App Variables
 */
const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

/**
 * App Configuration
 */
app.use(compression())
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"))
app.set("view engine", "pug")                         
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")))
app.use(express.json())                                
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(passport.initialize())                     
initialiseAuthentication(app)

/**
 * Routes Definition
 */
app.use('/', router)

async function establishConnection() {
  await connectToDatabase()
    .then(() => winston.log('info', 'Connection to database established.'))
    .catch(err => {
        winston.log('warn', 'Retrying')       
        setTimeout(establishConnection, 2000)
    })
}

/**
 * Server Activation
 */
app.listen(port, () => {
    establishConnection()
  })
```

Any suggestions? I am currently stuck here as this is the first time for me setting up an EC2 instance and with a nodejs app.

Comment: Even if .env doesn't contain a port, you should try setting port to 3000 in the listen method itself

Comment: I tried both ways, with and without the process.env.port. Didn't work.

Comment: I have also set up a node server on aws ec2 instance, but I always hardcode port into it.

Comment: Why don't you set a port in env file itself and then give it a go

Comment: If its accessible on the instance itself, then try to print the port. It can be a security issue

Comment: Tried the hardcoded variant you mentioned, without success. The app is running, but cant be accessed from outside. The machine is a windows server, could that be an issue?

Comment: No I don't think. Can you give me the ip address

Comment: Did you print the port

Comment: can you turn off the IIS sever and use port 80 on nodejs app ?  hit the url and see the output.. it will confirm the security group setting and reachablity

Comment: is your app starting and running fine on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Is the app listening to your "Public DNS (IPv4)"?
In order for the app to be accessible, it has to be ready to listen to requests coming through your Public DNS (IPv4) through port 3000 or "http://ec2-13-58-250-47.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3000".

Comment: I thought that's what the URL Rewrite module would be used for. I did it based on this tutorial: https://dev.to/massivebrains/deploying-node-express-app-on-a-windows-server-2l5c

Comment: based on the tutorial i do not need to change anything in the app itself.

Comment: The way I understand it is this:
1. Accessing my-URL shows the default IIS Template
2. Accessing my-URL/app shows 500 error
3. Adding a URL rewrite rule /app to "localhost:3000§ should resolve the error in 2
4. Accessing my-URL/app should now show the application, which is running on the EC2 instance.

But it doesn't show up.

Comment: @paaax yep the app is not the problem. You need to setup a proxy on your windows server that redirects requests to your app that's running on http://localhost:3000

Comment: that's why I am using IIS. I did it exactly as described in the tutorial

Comment: try this one https://dev.to/petereysermans/hosting-a-node-js-application-on-windows-with-iis-as-reverse-proxy-397b

Comment: it's the same approach. I read this one before. it's the same.

this gives me a 404 error: http://ec2-13-58-250-47.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/app:3000

Comment: Okay, what exactly do you need? I tried experimenting with different settings. First attempt was to host the application under "Default Web Site" by choosing "Add application". Second attempt was to host the application by adding a new website

Comment: ```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:3000/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```
web.config of /app

Comment: Did anyone resolve this issue?